# How many to select photo from windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I placed one image button when click on it need to select photo and selected image need to display in that image control.

1.Need to select a photo from gallery one type.

2.how to select photo from memory card folders?

Answer (score 3):

You can select an image from the device using the [PhotoChooserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.photochoosertask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

See example usage at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394019(v=vs.92).aspx